# How to split a string into N parts?

Tags: vb.net, string, split, limit

I'm trying to split a string into only *two* parts where the delimiter character can occur multiple times.

The code below doesn't work as I'm not allowed to specify a limit option:

```
Dim output = input.Split("=", 1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it does accept a limit parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: But i want to call "string.split("=")" instead of "Split(String, "=", 1)

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx then.

Comment: just curious...but why do you want to use "string.split("=")" instead of "Split(String, "=", 1) when it will do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [String.Split(Char[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Notice that the first parameter is a `Char` array, not a single character. The second parameter enables you to specify the maximum number of substrings to return.

**VB.NET**

```vb
Option Strict On
```

Important: You should always have the [strict compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to *On*.

```
Dim input As String = "aaaa=bbbb=cccc=dddd"
Dim separators As Char() = { "="c }
Dim count As Integer = 2
Dim options As StringSplitOptions = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
Dim output As String() = input.Split(separators, count, options)

For Each part As String In output
    Console.WriteLine(part)
Next
```

**C#**

```cs
string input = "aaaa=bbbb=cccc=dddd";
char[] separators = new[] { '=' };
int count = 2;
StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
string[] output = input.Split(separators, count, options);

foreach (string part in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

This will return an array containing two elements:

> aaaa
>   bbbb=cccc=dddd

Comment: There´s another problem on this: if input="parameter=value", everthing is fine. But it input="parameter=", i get a IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Sure, you need to check if the string contains a `=`. Just replace `2` with `If(input.Contains("="), 2, 1)`.